# How to run RAILS_ENV=production rake:db create with debug info?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-sql

I'm on the google cloud platform and I'm trying to create a the DB. When I run `RAILS_ENV=production rake:db create` I get the error

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"pass", "host"=>"183.195.230.182", "database"=>"dbname"}
```

This is a very broad error and it could be anything that is causing the error. I tried running the command with `--debugger` but that just failed.

What can I run with the command to get more info on what is causing it to fail?

Comment: Does google not provide you a database url the username and password already set?

Comment: No. unless you create an SQL instance, which I did in this case, they give you an instance with MySQL installed. You get a root username and pw, you can change the pw.

Comment: try running `rake db:setup`, and if that doesn't work, are you using a database on the instance, or a sql instance?

Comment: gives the error `Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'104.134.236.178' (using password: YES)` but the root password is correct. I even changed the rrot password to make sure and it still says its wrong. I can connect to mysql fine using those credentials

Comment: And you're certain the host is correct as well?

Comment: Can you please paste in a redacted version of your `config/database.yml` and a redacted tail of `log/production.log`

Comment: Turns out I had the wrong host IP address. Somehow mixed the SQL instance ip address and the normal server instance addresses up in the database.yml file

Comment: Happens to the best of us. You should totally delete this question though, or do what I do and answer it yourself, and mark it as read. Someone in the future is bound to run into the same problem.